# Endmorphisms of a Field

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let F is a field viewed as a module over itself. Prove that End(F) = F?, where End the  set of all endomorphism of F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

A more general statement for any commutative ring $R$ is that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R, R) \cong R$.

The key idea here is that any module homomorphism $\phi:R \rightarrow R$ is uniquely determined by $\phi(1)$.  Think about how you can use this information to define an isomorphism $\Psi: \operatorname{Hom}_R(R, R) \rightarrow R$, or in your case, an isomorphism $\Psi: \operatorname{End}(F) \rightarrow F$.

Comment: More generally, for any $R$-module $M$, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)\simeq M$.

Comment: Indeed!  @Bernard.  Thanks for the comment; I'm learning module theory for the first time myself.

Comment: More generally in a different way, without commutativity, $\hom(R_R,R_R) \cong R$, but way, $\hom(_RR,_RR) \cong R^{op}$